# How to delete a particular word from a file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file contains

**demo   demo1   demo2   demo3   demo12   demo13   demo23**

I just want to delete only one line contains **demo** with out delete other contents

Also I can't specify the line number. Line no: varies alternately

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\<wordtodelete\>//g' file.txt
```

This will also print the contents of the file to confirm the word is destroyed.

```
sed -e 's/\<wordtodelete\>//g' -i file.txt
```

Use `-i` if you want to overwrite the file in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/\b**demo**\b/d' filename
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these will help,

In `awk` you could use:

```
awk '{gsub("demo", "");print}' input
1 2 3 12 13 23
```

Using `perl` you could use:

```
perl -p -e 's/demo//g' input
1 2 3 12 13 23
```

Both the `awk` and `perl` use `regex` to match the word `demo`, then remove it from the line